# Scheduling start of a container in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have a short running container that does background processing (no ingress) that I have deployed to the Azure Container Apps service in Azure, my config is min replicas 0 (for when the container completes its work and exits) and max replicas 1 (i want only want one instance of my container running at any time).

I want to start my container once every hour, it generally runs for 3 mins and completes its task and closes.

Is there anyway with Azure Container Apps to schedule the start of my container?  At the moment I have reverted to running my Azure DevOps pipeline on a schedule which calls the az containerapp update command, but it feels like the wrong way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no scheduling concept in Container Apps. Here are some ideas:

1-Enable Ingress and create a Function or a Logic App that runs on a schedule and "ping" the Container App to start the process.

2-Create a Logic App that runs on a schedule and creates a Container Instance every hour, wait for it to complete, and delete it.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at option 2.  It appears there are prebuilt adapters for Azure Container Instances but not one (yet) for Azure Container Apps, probably because it is still in preview.  I guess I could get the logic app to run the az containerapp update command

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem now @DriveBlind ?

Answer (score 3):

This concept is now supported (in preview) via [Container App Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs).

Specific to your ask, the container app job [supports cron expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs?tabs=azure-cli#scheduled-jobs) at creation time, which would allow you to configure the schedule.

e.g.

`az containerapp job create ... --trigger-type "Schedule" --cron-expression "0 */1 * * *"`