# Schedule task in Azure to request Container App

Tags: python, azure, containers, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

I have a Container App in Azure cloud which hosts an API.

My goal is to execute a task which sends some specific requests to this API and sends e-mail with results. I want to run it twice a day. Let's say it's a single Python script task.py

What would be the best option to achieve that?
So far I've seen the following options:

1. Azure Functions
2. Logic Apps
3. Container Registry tasks???

Please note that container image used in the Container App is stored in Container Registry and contains task.py script too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling start of a container in Azure Container Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204957/scheduling-start-of-a-container-in-azure-container-apps)